# Update Expo SDK from 44 to 45, 46 or 47 not working

Tags: react-native, sdk, expo

I tryed several times to update the SDK Version in my project from 44 to 45,46 and 47.
Each time I try to update I receive the following issue:

Installed expo@^46.0.0
✔ Validated configuration.
✔ No additional changes necessary to app.json config.

✔ Updated known packages to compatible versions.
✔ Removed package-lock.json and deleted node_modules.
✖ Running npm install failed. Please check npm-error.log for more information.
✖ Failed to clear packager cache with error: Can't read JSON file: /Users/xxx/xxx/node_modules/expo/package.json
├─ File: /Users/xxx/xxx/node_modules/expo/package.json
└─ Cause: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/xxx/xxx/node_modules/expo/package.json'
✔ Cleared packager cache.
✔ Validated project

Automated upgrade steps complete.
...but this doesn't mean everything is done yet!

✅ The following packages were updated:
expo-app-loading, expo-font, expo-status-bar, expo-updates, react, react-dom, react-native, @react-native-async-storage/async-storage, react-native-gesture-handler, react-native-reanimated, react-native-safe-area-context, react-native-screens, react-native-web, react-native-webview, typescript, @babel/core, @types/react, @types/react-native, expo

The following packages were not updated. You should check the READMEs for those repositories to determine what version is compatible with your new set of packages:
@expo-google-fonts/inter, @reach/router, @react-native-community/masked-view, @react-navigation/bottom-tabs, @react-navigation/drawer, @react-navigation/native, @react-navigation/stack, accordion-collapse-react-native, axios, icomoon-react, localstorage-polyfill, moment, popup-ui, react-flex-router, react-modal, react-native-axios-jwt, react-native-base64, react-native-config, react-native-fetch-api, react-native-flash-message, react-native-modals, react-native-paper, react-native-popup-confirm-toast, react-native-popup-dialog, react-native-status-bar-height, react-native-table-component, react-native-vector-icons, react-tabbordion

Please refer to the release notes for information on any further required steps to update and information about breaking changes:
https://blog.expo.dev/expo-sdk-46-c2a1655f63f7

You should also look at the breaking changes from a release that you skipped:

- https://blog.expo.dev/expo-sdk-45-f4e332954a68

After updating, the folder node_modules is missing.
What am I doing wrong??

Comment: what version of `expo-cli` are you on?  What commands were you running?  Please give more details

Comment: you can also manually remove `node_modules` and anything else related to those packages and try again.  What other debugging steps have you taken?

Answer (score 1):

You can also manually remove `.expo`, run `expo upgrade`